# .htaccess for php switch case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a friendly url for my website but when i use it, it always uses the current folder as rewrite and not show images, css,...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^number/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=read&num=$1 [L,NC]
```

and i have result as mydomain.com/number/123456/
but my page not showing with theme because all link js,css,images,... change in to /number/123456/

example: mydomain.com/number/123456/css/style.css or mydomain.com/number/123456/images/logo.png

But all that in root folder is mydomain.com/css and mydomain.com/images ~~!
How can i use with that format and my page can show correctly :(

Any solutions?

Please help me!

Comment: Your `.htaccess` look weird when changing lines.

Comment: No. My file line by line. I don't know why im post it here it same line :(

Comment: Reformat your question and post .htaccess again otherwise its not readable.

Comment: Use Code instead of Quote.

Comment: Im edited my post. Plz help me. Hop guys can understand me.